# How to know if user has closed message component Primefaces

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere. Basically I have a web services that sends notifications to a client and that client displays the message using **Primefaces message component**.

The first time the screen is loaded I want  to display the notification, but **if the user closes that message box I do not want to render it again until a next session is opened**.

I tried grabbing the component in javascript and setting a `.on("click", function () {})` to it, but that only seemed to work on chrome's dev console, if I tried the same code on the actual page nothing would happen. So I thought "*I'm going to use the message component widget var to get ahold of it*", but the component does not seem to have a widgetvar attribute.

Now I'm doing something very finnick, I use `$(document).ready(function () {})`  to run a remote command once the pages finished loading that uses a counter to check whether or not I can set a variable to false, that variable is then used in the rendered attribute of the message. But there is gotta be a more proper solution to this, **how can I execute a function when a message component gets closed** ?

My intuition would let me to believe that there would be something like a `onClose` attribute on the message component, but there isn't. I also can't place a `<p:ajax event='close' />` inside of the message as that creates an error.

Comment: Please read [ask] (search, keep track, mention) and [mcve]. version info. And the source of PF is open...

Comment: @Kukeltje he can achieve this, in the POSTCONSTRUCT, how? simple use a boolean that is set to true in the POSTCONSTRUCT, then call the method that displays the message (also in the POSTCONSTRUCT), inside this method, check if the boolean is true and display the message, then set the boolean to false, and then when your method that prints message is called again it wont print it because the boolean will always be false since it will only be true once on the postconstruct, ask me if you didn't get something or need clarification, hope it helps :)

Comment: See the initial comment.... code is worth a 1000 words

Comment: Thank you @BugsForBreakfast I'll give that a try.